# Alternative to scala structural types in the serialization layer

Tags: scala, serialization, avro

In the way of solving the serialization layer in my current project, I've stumbled across on Scala structural types. I'm using [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) to build this layer where scala classes are being generated automatically from Avro schemas thanks to an [sbt plugin](https://github.com/cavorite/sbt-avro). Of course my intention is not to have to write both a serializer and a deserializer for each entity we need to deal with. So, in a first attempt, and taking into account that this is my first serious project with Scala, I've ended up with a code like this:

```
object AvroSer {

  type AvroEntity = { def getSchema(): org.apache.avro.Schema }

  def serialize[T <: AvroEntity](entity: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Array[Byte] = {
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter(m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
    val dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter(datumWriter)
    dataFileWriter.create(entity.getSchema, baos)
    dataFileWriter.append(entity)
    dataFileWriter.close()
    baos.toByteArray
  }

  def deserialize[T <: AvroEntity](bytes: Array[Byte], entityClass: Class[T])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    val is = new SeekableByteArrayInput(bytes)
    val datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader(m.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
    val dataFileReader = new DataFileReader(is, datumReader)
    dataFileReader.next()
  }

}
```

As you can see, the solution relies on a combination of structural types and Manifest[T] in order to not repeat myself writing one (de)serializer per entity belonging to my domain. So far so good. However, It's known that structural types can involve a hard impact in performance as they use reflection to make it work. That's why I'm wondering if there's another alternative (maybe type classes) that didn't have these drawbacks.

It's important to highlight that domain scala classes are being generated automatically so that there's no an easy way to modify these classes (for instance implementing some kind of inheritance).

BTW, the scala version is 2.10.3.

Any ideas?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A nitpick: structural typing is more of a *reverse* of duck typing. The latter says "I don't care what the types are, as long as I can access these members". The former says "I'm *defining* a specific type that has these members, and any other type that has these members should 'fit' for this type". It's important to be aware of the difference so as not to burn oneself.

Comment: Understood. I've edited the question removing all references to duck typing. Thanks.